# Take picture in PhoneGap using FILE_URI with remote base url

Tags: ios, camera, cordova

I have a phonegap application which is initialized from a remote URL.  I want to take a picture and display it in the app.  Per [the documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture), I am using FILE_URI as the destination type:

> Note: The image quality of pictures taken using the camera on newer
>   devices is quite good, and images from the Photo Album will not be
>   downscaled to a lower quality, even if a quality parameter is
>   specified. **Encoding such images using Base64 has caused memory issues
>   on many newer devices. Therefore, using FILE_URI as the
>   'Camera.destinationType' is highly recommended.**

In my success callback, I try to set the `src` attribute of an `img` to the `file://` URI returned by phonegap, and I get the standard browser error, "Not allowed to load local resource".

Is there a way to configure a phonegap iOS app to allow access to local files from a remote page?